# How to get the sum price from table using accounting.js in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had a hard time getting the sum price of each row in my table. Im using accounting library in my price for currency purposes and it does not get the actual total price because of the character and the comma when the price exceed to thousands.

---

This is my rows when appending to the table

```
$('body').on('click','.js-add',function(){
        var target = $(this);
        var product = target.attr('data-product');
        var price = target.attr('data-price');
        var barcode = target.attr('data-barcode');
        var unit = target.attr('data-unt');     
        swal("Enter number of item to buy:", {
            content: "input",
        })
        .then((value) => {
            if (value == "") {
                swal("Error","Entered none!","error");
            }else{
                var qtynum = parseInt(value);
                if (isNaN(qtynum)){
                    swal("Error","Please input a valid number!","error");
                }else{
                    var total = value * price;
                    $('#tableData').append("<tr><td>"+barcode+"</td><td>"+product+"</td><td>₱"+price+"</td><td>"+unit+"</td><td>"+value+"</td><td class='totalPrice'>"+accounting.formatMoney(total,{symbol:"₱",format: "%s %v"})+"</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger' type='button' id='delete-row' style='padding:0px;'>&times</button><tr>");
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
```

---

This is what I've done so far for adding all the prices in the table.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var TotalValue = 0;
    $("#tableData tr").each(function(){
          TotalValue += parseFloat($(this).find('.totalPrice').text());
    });
    alert(TotalValue);
});
```

I'd put alert for testing purposes. The TotalValue will be shown on the outside of the table. Hope someone will give me an idea to solve this.

Comment: it seems like the raw data are stored in the data-attributes of your elements. Can you please share how is your DOM when you try to get the total

Comment: The data is from my database so I'd use this one.`if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr class='js-add' data-barcode=".$row['id']." data-product=".$row['product_name']." data-price=".$row['sell_price']." data-unt=".$row['unit']."><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['product_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>₱".$row['sell_price']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['unit']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['quantity']."</td>";
   }
  }
  else{
   echo "<td></td><td>No Products found!</td><td></td>";
  }
 }?>`

Comment: I'd stored my data in data-attributes for transferring it to other table.

Comment: Please edit your question, it's not lisible like that. I just want to see the compiled version of this, not with the php. (Seen in console)

Comment: Sorry for that. When I run the the jquery for adding all the price in the table it return 0. I think its because my table data is ₱1,000.00 something like that the function cannot get the actual data.

Comment: What I was expecting is that the value unformatted was stored in the data-attribute of the element

Comment: Yes its unformatted. I only format it for user convenient. The problem is I cant get  all the data from my table because its dynamic.

Comment: Ah get it. There's some libraries to format number https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize#number-module

Comment: I already formatted my the numbers into currency. I cant get the sum of those.

Comment: You have to format them on the fly for your calculation as number.

Comment: If they have always same format ',' as thousand separator you can replace them on the fly instead of using a library. `parseFloat($(this).find('.totalPrice').text().replace(\,\g,""))`

Comment: Ahh okay I get it thanks.

Comment: `accounting.formatMoney(price,{symbol:"₱",format: "%s %v"})` is this a problem when getting the sum? I tried what you suggested and it says **invalid escape string sequence**

Comment: You have to replace your money symbol with empty text too

Comment: It returns NaN. I'd used parseFloat($(this).find('.totalPrice').text().replace(/,/g,"P")) because it says invalid escape string. It returns NaN

Comment: Try this `parseFloat($(this).find('.totalPrice').text().replace(\,\g,"").replace("₱",""))`

Comment: Still returns NaN. accounting.formatMoney(price,{symbol:"₱",format: "%s %v"}) returns ₱ 1,000.00 like that.

Comment: sorry it's my bad, it's not anti slash but slashes `parseFloat($(this).find('.totalPrice').text().replace(/,/g,"").replace("₱",""))`

Comment: But still returning Nan. I'd tried modify but still returning Nan. I tried removing parseFloat and it shows the numbers with .00 maybe this one?